# How can I unit test assignment to window.location on an Angular JS projection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine

I'm working on an AngularJS/Javascript Single Page Application(SAP) that sits behind a custom reverse-proxy, using Keycloak for Single-Sign-On(SSO).

When the user clicks "logout", after doing some other things, the application will execute

```
window.location = reverseProxyHost + '/logout';
```

to ensure the user is completely logged-out, not just from this application, but from all applications authorized by the Keycloak SSO.

If we allow this line to execute, Karma complains

> Some of your tests did a full page reload!

This Error fails the entire test suite.

It doesn't seem that I can override the `window.location` object value from the context of my test.

If I create a `localContext` object and then attempt

```
with(localContext){
```

the test will fail because `with` is incompatible with `'use strict'`.

Any ideas how I can ensure the line is being executed with expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$window` from angular, and `$window.location.replace` instead of `window.location = "newlocation.com"`. 
Then you shourd be able to mock like this:

```
  var $window = { location: { replace: jasmine.createSpy('replace') } };
  module('app', function ($provide) {
     $provide.value('$window', $window);
  });
```

Comment: Looks promising.  Will try tommorow.  Thanks!